# getting SSG instead of ISR during build time in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create an ISR page that has two dynamic routes with next.js. I added `revalidate: 18000` to `getStaticProps` but when I run `yarn run build` I notice that my page is SSG, not ISR. here are my `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` functions, can anybody tell me what's wrong :

---

note: `getZonesApi` is for the first route and `getServicesApi` is for the second route

```
  export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const zoneData = await getZonesApi();
    const servicesData = [];
    zoneData.forEach((zone) => {
      getServicesApi(zone.id).then((res) => {
        const data = res.map((item) => {
          return {
            ...item,
            zoneId: zone.id,
          };
        });
        servicesData.push(data);
      });
    });

    const data = servicesData.flat();

    return {
      paths: data.map((service) => {
        return {
          params: {
            zoneId: service.zoneId,
            serviceId: service.id,
          },
        };
      }),
      fallback: "blocking",
    };
  };

  export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { zoneId, serviceId } }) => {
    const data = await getServiceApi(zoneId, serviceId);

    return {
      props: { data: data || null },
      revalidate: 18000,
    };
  };
```

as you can see `/[zoneId]/[serviceId]` route is SSG :
[image]